# How to translate this code from PHP in AdonisJS?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, json, adonis.js

I have some code in PHP and i should translate it in AdonisJS.But i don't know PHP.

This is for an endpoint for an api.

```
    $comenzi = $app['db']->fetchAll("select * from user_comenzi where user_id = ? order by id desc",array($user['id']));
    $comenziArray = array();
    foreach ($comenzi as $comanda) {
      $comandaObject = json_decode($comanda['comanda'],true);
      if (count($comandaObject['items']) === 0 ) {
        continue;
      }
      $comandaObject['id'] = $comanda['id'];
      $comenziArray[] = $comandaObject;
    }
    return $app->json($comenziArray);
  });
```

You guys don't need to translate it, you can just explain me what this code makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database query finds all rows in the `user_comenzi` table where `user_id` is the value of `$user['id']`, which is something that was set earlier (presumably the ID of the current user of the script). It then loops over all the rows returned by the query.

`$comenziArray` is an array that will contain the results.

It uses the `comanda` and `id` columns of the row.

`comanda` is a JSON object, which it decodes into an associative array. It contains an `items` array; if this array is empty, it skips this row.

It adds the `id` column from the row as an `id` element of the associative array.

Then the associative array is added to `$comenziArray`.

After the loop is finished, it converts `$comenziArray` to JSON and returns that to the caller.

To summarize, it's returning a JSON array of all the `comanda` objects associated with the given user, skipping the ones where `items` is empty, and adding the `id` of the row into each corresponding object.